# How do I change document root folder in localhost

Tags: apache, directory, localhost, wamp

I'm developing a website that has directories and sub-directories and I'm using a relative path. I'm using WAMP and I create folders for all my projects separately. Whenever I use "/" as the path, it links to localhost as the root path, but my website is in localhost/newproject. How do I get it to link to localhost/newproject instead of localhost. I don't want to use absolute path cos that means I will have to update the links when I upload the website.

Ps: It works well on live server but on my local machine, it's linking to localhost instead of localhost/newproject